# Capture images from a phone camera?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need a simple way to capture images from smartphones without writing an app for every Operating System ( android, ios, winphone ).

Is there a way to capture images from a phone camera ( obviously without using OS API ) on a web page ?

Comment: This seems to be related http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: try sencha touch or phonegap

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

Your best bet is to use Apache Cordova. However, note that the web page needs to be wrapped in a native WebView as an app, as it is not possible to take a picture using the phone's camera directly from a web page. The advantage of using Cordova/Phonegap is that you do not need to write custom code for each platform.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/index.html

[Usage example](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera)

Comment: Yes, here is a simple trick....
`<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">`